# Interaction with two variables as parameters, saving the raster properties output into a table (.dbf)

Tags: modelbuilder, field-calculator, parameters, loop, hillshade

The draft of the model below

**TASK**: I need to calculate the percentage of river channel that is covered with shadow in each timestep

**RESOURCS:** I have values for azimuth and elevation of the sun (hourly timestep for daylight hours within a year – over 3000 values)

**INPUTS:** 
1.  A table (.dbf) with azimuth and elevation values
2.  A river chanel mask (single polygon)
3.  A DSM

**PROBLEMS**

**How to make an interaction with two lists as parameters**

The elevation value and azimuth value are assingned to a certain time and date,  .I don’t want to calculate hillshade for e.g  elevation row 2 and azimuth row 6 –I want  only elevation row 1 + azimuth row 1, elevation row 2 + azimuth row 2, elevation row 3 + azimuth row 3… etc…

**How to save an output – all the means -  back to the input table** 
– I had an idea to use a calculate field tool, but I don’t know how to “import” the values to the expression field.

---

I've figured out the solution to my first problem. It was easier than I thought. I Do not need to iterate. The simple for of input variable as a list and specifying the table to derive the values.
But there is still the other problem - how to write the output back to the input table as a next column[image: model]

Answer (score 1):

If you have two sources, first join them together, either by spatial or attribute criteria.
Then you can use columns of both data sources in the Field calculator.

[Field calculation examples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/) using code blocks and multiple parameters.

Comment: I do have only one source: a table with 3 columns: time, elevation, azimuth (and many many rows...) I want to run the HILLSHADE tool with parameters derived from each row. 
I use ModelBuilder.
So far I've managed to run the procedure for one row manually, so I know that it works and as a result I get the raster with shadows within the river channel. But if I will run the model I will have multiple rasters. For each I would like to calculatethe mean and write it to the input table - so I will have output table contaning 4 columns: time, elevation, azimuth and mean